# Is the running average a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

$\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n, \ldots$ - summable random variables, for every natural n: $\mathcal F_n = \sigma(\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n)$ and $\xi_1 + \ldots + \xi_n \over n$ = $\mathbb E(\xi_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n)$.
Prove that this sequence: $X_n \triangleq \frac {\xi_1 + \ldots + \xi_n} n$ is a martingale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $X_{n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{n}$-measurable and $E\left[|X_{n}|\right]<\infty$.
We go to show that $E\left[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]=X_{n}$.
By direct calculation,
\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right] & = & E\left[\frac{\xi_{n+1}}{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]+E\left[\frac{\xi_{1}+\ldots+\xi_{n}}{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{n+1}\cdot E\left[\xi_{n+1}\mid\mathcal{F}_{n}\right]+\frac{\xi_{1}+\ldots+\xi_{n}}{n+1}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\frac{\xi_{1}+\ldots+\xi_{n}}{n}+\frac{\xi_{1}+\ldots+\xi_{n}}{n+1}\\
 & = & \frac{\xi_{1}+\ldots+\xi_{n}}{n}\left\{ \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{n}{n+1}\right\} \\
 & = & X_{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $\{X_{n},\,\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a martingale with respect
to the filtrarion $\{\mathcal{F}_{n},\,\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.